# Functions with class arguments are leaked from a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup

I have a small piece of code here for your consideration which puzzles me quite a lot. The strange thing is that it compiles on both Sun Studio and GCC even though I think it should not.

Consider this:

```
namespace name
{
  class C
    {
      int a;
    };

  void f(C c);
  void g(int a);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  name::C c;

  name::f(c); 
  f(c);  // <--- this compiles, strangely enough

  name::g(42);
  // g(42);  <--- this does not, as I expected
}
```

The class argument from the same namespace causes the function `f` to 'leak' out of the namespace and be accessible without `name::`.

Does anybody have an explanation for this? It is certainly me and not the compiler being wrong here.

Comment: Interesting, BTW intel compiler (icpc) compiles this as well...

Comment: Edited my own question in order to remove the irrelevant bits and make it easier to find for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's called [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenig_lookup) (or Koenig lookup). In short, the compiler will look for the function in namespaces that are the namespaces of argument types.

Comment: @lytenyn: it's one you use everyday though :) `std::string s; s += "aa";`, here `+=` comes from the `std` namespace even though you never specified it, thanks to ADL.

Comment: @matthieu-m: you are perfectly right, of course, same thing when using iostreams. But these are the small things you never think about unless someone pushes your nose into it :)
Also, I cannot recall any C++ book I read ever mentioning it, even though it is so fundamental. This might just be my memory, of course.

Answer (score 12):

This is [Argument-Dependent Name Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), a.k.a. ADL, a.k.a. Koenig lookup. This was invented to make operators work as expected, e.g.:

```
namespace fu {
    struct bar { int i; };
    inline std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const bar& b ) {
        return o << "fu::bar " << b.i;
    }
}

fu::bar b;
b.i = 42;
std::cout << b << std::endl; // works via ADL magic
```

Without ADL you'd have to either explicitly bring the output operator with ugly `using fu::operator<<;`, or use even uglier explicit call:

```
fu::operator<<( std::cout, b ) << std::endl;
```

Comment: The article is very short, where's your curiosity?

Answer (score 7):

It's due to "argument dependent lookup".  Removing the const will not change the behavior you're seeing.  To demonstrate that it's ADL, try moving the St struct outside of the namespace...

```
struct St
{
   int a;
};

namespace name
{
  void f(const St& st);
  void g(int a);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  St st;

  name::f(st); 
  f(st);  // <--- now you will get the expected compile error

  name::g(42);
  // g(42);  <--- this does not, as I expected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is caused by *argument dependent lookup*.