# make_pair namespace pollution

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, std-pair

In the code I've been writing recently, I've noticed a strange behaviour.

When I use `make_pair` with the first argument being an `std::pair`, `make_pair` becomes "magically" available in the namespace (I don't have to use an `std::` qualifier)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
    int i1 = 2; int i2 = 10; int i3 = 0;

    // constructing a pair using std::make_pair, everything's okay
    std::pair<int,int> key = std::make_pair(i1, i2);

    // here, why is make_pair suddenly magically available without the
    // std:: namespace qualifier?
    // At the same time, using ::make_pair yields and error
    // (make_pair has not declared...)
    std::pair<std::pair<int,int>, int> mypair = make_pair(key, i3);

    std::cout << mypair.first.first << "\n";
    std::cout << mypair.first.second << "\n";
    std::cout << mypair.second << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The compiles just fine (with `-Wall and -pedantic-errors`) and outputs:

```
2
10
0
```

Why is this happening? I've looked into cppreference and didn't find any hint of this behaviour being correct. Am I missing anything?

FYI, I'm using gcc 4.6.3

Comment: [Argument dependent (a.k.a. Koenig) lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). Some useful SO links/possible dups: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886478/functions-with-class-arguments-are-leaked-from-a-namespace/4886535#4886535), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276772/why-was-argument-dependent-lookup-invented), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/detailed-explanation-on-how-koenig-lookup-works-with-namespaces-and-why-its-a-go/8111750#8111750).

Comment: that was fast... thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, well written question, btw. ADL is not without its problems, this is a good read: [What are the pitfalls of ADL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958648/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-adl)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's a less-known feature of C++, as @jrok pointed out blazingly fast, Koenig Lookup, or in modern C++ <sup>1)</sup>, **ADL** (Argument-Dependent Lookup). What it does is basically searches in the namespaces of the arguments for the function that you want to call (`make_pair` in this example). The argument triggering the ADL is obviously `std::pair`.

<sup>1)</sup><sub>the naming has been changed, though a lot of people know the first term</sub>

---

Perhaps it's worth mentioning that ADL is quite important for one particular type of function: operators. If not for ADL, it would be impossible for even the trivial C++ "hello, world!" to work, because this:

```
std::cout << "Hello, world!";
```

Would have to be written as this:

```
std::operator<< (std::cout, "Hello, world!");
```

Thanks to ADL, `<<` is properly resolved to be in `std` namespace.

---

References:

- [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)
- Great video by Stephan T. Lavavej, [Core C++ Part 1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-1-of-n)
- [A broader look on ADL and its uses by Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill08.htm)
- It can be found in The C++ Standard (I was using n3485 version) in **§ 3.4.2**